# Python dictionary initialization?

Tags: python

I am not sure if this is a bug or a feature.
I have a dictionary to be initialized with empty lists.

Lets say

```
keys =['one','two','three']
sets = dict.fromkeys(keys,[])
```

What I observed is if you append any item to any of the lists all the lists are modified.

```
sets = dict.fromkeys(['one','two','three'],[])
sets['one'].append(1)
```

sets

```
{'three': [1],'two': [1], 'one': [1]}
```

But when I do it manually using loop,

```
for key in keys:
      sets[key] = []
sets['one'].append(1)
```

sets

```
{'three': [], 'two': [], 'one': [1]}
```

I would think the second behavior should be the default.

Comment: This question comes in so many different shapes and forms.

Comment: It's likely you would have been best served here by `collections.defaultdict`.  Declare it like this: `sets = collections.defaultdict(list)`.

Comment: why are you using lists instead of sets for a variable named sets?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how things work in Python.

When you use `fromkeys()` in this manner, you end with three references to the same list. When you change one list, all three appear to change.

The same behaviour can also be seen here:

```
In [2]: l = [[]] * 3

In [3]: l
Out[3]: [[], [], []]

In [4]: l[0].append('one')

In [5]: l
Out[5]: [['one'], ['one'], ['one']]
```

Again, the three lists are in fact three references to the same list:

```
In [6]: map(id, l)
Out[6]: [18459824, 18459824, 18459824]
```

(notice how they have the same id)

Comment: The easiest way to explain this, I find, is it's exactly the same as doing `mylist = []` followed by `sets = dict.fromkeys(keys, mylist)` - just as in that case, where `mylist` is the value for every key, when you pass an empty list `[]` it's the same empty list every time. The reason for this is that in Python, variables are always references.

Comment: That is why `defaultdict` uses [a factory of default values](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.default_factory), not the value itself. It's strange that `dict.fromkeys` doens't follow the same technique.

Comment: Not so strange, the help states: `dict.fromkeys(S[,v]) -> New dict with keys from S and values equal to v.`

Comment: @MikeyB I mean it would be better if they implemented `dict.fromkeys` the same way as `defaultdict`. With the current implementation of `dict.fromkeys` coders have to use some roundabout ways to achive the necessary functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I just found it to be a weird behavior from python.

Answer (score 5):

Other answers covered the 'Why', so here's the how.

You should use a comprehension to create your desired dictionary:

```
>>> keys = ['one','two','three']
>>> sets = { x: [] for x in keys }
>>> sets['one'].append(1)
>>> sets
{'three': [], 'two': [], 'one': [1]}
```

For Python 2.6 and below, the dictionary comprehension can be replaced with:

```
>>> sets = dict( ((x,[]) for x in keys) )
```

Comment: otherwise the following might help: `dict(zip(keys, ([] for x in keys)))`

Comment: @MikeyB Sorry my mistake. Also 

        dict([(x,[]) for x in keys])

Not sure which is faster, generator or list comp